# Large Deviation, Optimal Transport and Machine Learning Reference

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, machine-learning, large-deviation-theory, optimal-transport

I am looking for references (books/sites/articles) on the following three subjects: Large Deviation, Optimal Transport and Machine Learning References. I would like works which involve any of them individually, or jointly. My motivation for this is the following course description which used to be taught at my school:

> Two mathematical frameworks: optimal transport and large deviation
>   theory, can be combined to provide tools and methods of analysis for
>   some central tasks in data science: classification, clustering and
>   regression, dimensionality reduction, conditional probability
>   estimation, prediction of rare events. Recurring themes will include
>   the power of the composition of simple functions to capture complex
>   behavior - as demonstrated by neural networks - and of the
>   characterization of both the available observations of the system
>   under study and the parameters tuned to model it in terms of
>   underlying probability distributions.

If you know of any core books on either Large Deviation or Optimal Trasport that can be grasped at a beginning graduate level, I would much appreciate it!

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For optimal transport, have a look at this book: "https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00567". For large deviations, the standard Springer reference book by Dembo and Zeitouni is a bit tough; the short book by van Hollander is somewhat easier.

I will say, though, that "beginning graduate level" is possibly a stretch. The recent optimal transport book by Santambrogio (also good) says point blank that you'll have a tough time if you don't already have a decent background in functional analysis and measure theory, and I think the same is true for large deviations.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a bit late, but I can supplement the other answers.

For general introduction to the topics you mentioned :

Optimal transport : Villani's "Optimal Transport Old and New" book is great.

Large Deviations : I think Dembo and Zeitouni's book is good. Hollanders book is ok, but contains a bit less content.

Machine Learning : There is a lecture course on youtube which is good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XmGyd4smUs&list=PL8FnQMH2k7jzhtVYbKmvrMyXDYMmgjj_n&index=2 .

There has been a lot of work done w.r.t Large Deviations (Sanov theorem, and Friedlin-Wentzell theory) in determining the cost function of gradient flows  in measure spaces (this topic branches probability theory, thermodynamics, differential geometry, optimal transport) . See Peletiers works, in particular https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7591.

Answer (score 2):

Just in order to add also one particular and comparably famous reference combining aspects of OT and large deviations:
**S Adams, Nicolas Dirr, M Peletier, J Zimmer**;
From a large-deviations principle to the Wasserstein gradient flow: a new micro-macro passage

https://researchportal.bath.ac.uk/en/publications/from-a-large-deviations-principle-to-the-wasserstein-gradient-flo

Answer (score 0):

For large deviation theory in general (and applications in statistical mechanics), see R. Ellis' notes: [https://people.math.umass.edu/~rsellis/pdf-files/Les-Houches-lectures.pdf](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Ersellis/pdf-files/Les-Houches-lectures.pdf)